# Flutter firebase_messaging android app crash on .getToken() call

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package with my flutter app. Usually it works(version 7.0.3) fine with the code I'm using(see below) but since the null-safety version was released my code doesn't work anymore. I wonder if someone could help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?

**Error causing code**

```
try {
    fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
} catch (error) {
    print(error);
}
```

**Error output**

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/Metadata;
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.lambda$getToken$1$FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin(FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:165)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin$p8YQXDuFBNIxl8PFaPCQJtYc3sw.call(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzv.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.Metadata" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~uCa7QFzhvu5i_TZpnqat0w==/com.example.****-1cbY-LKuCoOsfZybV-Gq6g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~uCa7QFzhvu5i_TZpnqat0w==/com.example.****-1cbY-LKuCoOsfZybV-Gq6g==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~uCa7QFzhvu5i_TZpnqat0w==/com.example.****-1cbY-LKuCoOsfZybV-Gq6g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8942):    ... 6 more
```

**app -> src -> main -> kotlin -> Application.kt**

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry

import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin

class Application() : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        val key: String? = FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin::class.java.canonicalName
        if (!registry?.hasPlugin(key)!!) {
            FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        }
    }
}
```

**app -> src -> main -> kotlin -> MainActivity.kt**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For me, it worked by downgrading from

`com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1`

to

`com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0`

Hint: this is a temporary solution for those versions:

`firebase_messaging: ^9.1.4`
`firebase_core: ^1.1.1`

Comment: I think bom28 is buggy, plus getToken needs vapidKey now. Not seeing that in bom26

Comment: Downgrading to 27.0.0 also solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: My problem was with react.js, but replacing the library with 27.0.0 certainly fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

For some reason I had put the *onBackgroundMessageHandler* as a class method in my project. The problem were resolved by simply placing the method as a *top-level function* as it should be.

**Before**

```
class MyNotificationClass {
      Future<dynamic> onBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
        print('on Background $message');
      }

      // ...
    }
```

**After**

```
Future<dynamic> onBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
            print('on Background $message');
          }

class MyNotificationClass {
          // ...
        }
```

**android -> app -> src -> build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')

    // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**android -> build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3' // 3.5.0
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2' // 4.3.2
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.5 #^0.14.4 #^0.13.5                     
  firebase_database: ^6.1.2 #4.4.0                             
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3 #^0.5.3 #^0.4.4+3                       
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.0 #0.18.4+1 #^0.16.0                     
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.1 #7.0.3 #^6.0.15                   
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.0 #0.6.3 #^0.5.0+11             
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.0 #6.3.0 #^5.0.11                   
  cloud_functions: ^1.0.3 #0.7.2 #^0.5.0
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="app name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'm not using onBackgroundMessageHandler at all and yet I'm getting the same crash

Comment: Hmm. I can post my configuration files and you can try to edit your files and see if it works? Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked by downgrading from com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1 to 27.0.0

Comment: Nice! I'm glad you managed to solve it. Happy coding!